# Replace commas with LF - BUT keeping color formatting within cell?

Tags: excel, formatting, cell, vba

I have a list of names within a cell, that differ in color and are separated by comma. All I want to achieve now is to replace the commas with a LF.   I can only find replacement methods that then also remove the different coloring of the names ( e.g. Cells.Replace ( "," ,  ""&CHR(10) & "", ....). Any suggestions ?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible in formula's.  It could be done using VBA from what I'm reading... http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/265158-concatenate-keep-formatting.html

Answer (score 1):

You would need to loop:

```
Sub replaceCommas()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        For n = 1 To Len(cell.Value2)
            If cell.Characters(n, 1).Text = "," Then cell.Characters(n, 1).Text = vbLf
        Next n
    Next cell
End Sub
```

for example. Note that there can be issues with accessing Characters if the cells contain a lot of text.